# Unrecognized rule in Flex lexer

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer

In the process of making an XML parser :

As the title suggests I have documented the rules as shown in my code below , but flex seems to *miss* a specific one.

Error : [Cmd Error Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr2Hu.jpg)

The line in question is :

````c
{boolean}        {yylval.booleanval  = strdup(yytext); if(err==1){printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t");}; return BOOLEAN;}```
````

When clearly declared flex seems to disregard it, where for the other rules no such problem arises.

Flex Code :

```c
    %option noyywrap
    %option yylineno

    string   [_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*
    digit    [0-9]
    integer  {digit}+
    boolean  "True" | "False"
    text ({string}| )*

    %%
    .                          {printf("%s",yytext);}
    {boolean}                  {yylval.booleanval  = strdup(yytext); if(err==1){printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t");}; return BOOLEAN;}
    {integer}                  {return INT;}
    {string}                   {return STRING;}

    %%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rereading the question, I think there is a terminology problem. The *rule* is

```
{boolean}   {yylval.booleanval  = strdup(yytext); if(err==1){printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t");}; return BOOLEAN;}
```

Like all rule, that rule consists of *pattern" and an action. The pattern `{boolean}` consists only of a macro expansion. Once the macro is expanded, the line can no longer be recognised as a rule because of stray whitespace in the macro's definition, as I explained in the original answer below:

---

As indicated by the error message, the problem is the pattern in line 22 of your flex file, which contains a macro expansion of `boolean`:

```
boolean  "True" | "False"
```

Flex patterns may not contain unquoted whitespace, whether entered directly or through a macro.

If you insist on using a macro, it could be:

```
boolean  True|False
```

Although nothing prevents you from inserting the pattern directly in the rule:

```
True|False   {yylval.booleanval  = strdup(yytext); if(err==1){printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t");}; return BOOLEAN;}
```

Comment: That seems to solve it thank you , but something else emerges. I get a warning that the rules from line 55-58 can not be matched. Is this because of that former declaration of boolean? Or is it something extra?

Comment: @P.Evripidis: no. It's because any of those would already be matched by `[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*`.